# font-awesome loading not centered

Tags: html, css, font-awesome

I'm using font-awesome for my loading notification, but it's driving me crazy that there is just a slight offset causing the rotation to have a "wobble"

html

```
<div class="loading-div fa fa-cog fa-spin"></div>
```

css

```
.loading-div{
    position: absolute;
    z-index: 9999;
    font-size: 200px;
}
```

https://jsfiddle.net/69x2j60j/

I noticed that it's containing div is not square, but if I try to set height, width to static pixels it only gets worse... thoughts?

Answer (score 3):

As you said yourself, the `div` isn't square so that's going to give you a bit of "wobble" as it rotates. Set the `line-height` (rather than `height`) and `width` properties to equal values and set `text-align` to `center` and it should smooth things out a bit for you.

If it you're still getting a slight "wobble" then it may just be a rendering issue in your browser. Font Awesome is, I believe, optimised to be displayed at `14px`, or multiples thereof, so try reducing the `font-size` to `196px`.

[Here](https://jsfiddle.net/69x2j60j/2/) is an updated Fiddle with 2 animations, the first with the dimensions set and the second with the dimensions set and the `font-size` reduced.

And here's an extract with the properties relavant to the "fix":

```
.loading-div{
    font-size:196px;
    line-height:200px;
    text-align:center;
    width:200px;
}
```

Comment: unfortunately this isn't working either.. I appreciate the attempt

Comment: Check the updates above, @godmode,  see if they're of any help.

Comment: @godmode I don't see any wobble in the 2nd cog. It's pretty awesome, I was also looking to correct this before. Way2go Shaggy!

Comment: :/ sorry still no luck

Comment: Even with the adjustment to the `font-size`? What browser are you using?

Comment: Font-size was the key in my case.

Answer (score -1):

To center horizontally, use this (relevant CSS):

```
.stripes{
    text-align: center;
}

.loading-div{
    display: inline-block;
}
```

FIDDLE: https://jsfiddle.net/lmgonzalves/69x2j60j/1/

Comment: I appreciate your attempt, but I wasn't looking for centering in the div. It's almost like the cog itself is not a perfect circle